# What is the purpose of a closed constructed type?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm studying generics types in C#, and I have found this MSDN article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f.aspx about generic classes. Almost everything is OK, but I have a doubt respect to **closed constructed type** concept.

So, I decided to write some test code to explore the concept:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace Articulos.Cap03
{
    internal class ClaseBase <T> { }
    internal class SubclaseGenerica<T> : ClaseBase <long> { }

    internal class HerenciaCerrada
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            SubclaseGenerica<decimal> sg1 = new SubclaseGenerica<decimal>();
            SubclaseGenerica<Object> sg2 = new SubclaseGenerica<Object>();
            SubclaseGenerica<ArrayList> sg3 = new SubclaseGenerica<ArrayList>();
        }
    }
}
```

It compiles and executes correctly.

What is the porpuse of:

```
internal class SubclaseGenerica<T> : ClaseBase <long> { }
```

[**Note**: I thought it restricts the parameter type of SubclaseGenerica to `long` primitive type.]

Comment: The `T` of `ClaseBase` and the `T` of `SubclaseGenerica` are independent (just like two variables with the same name but in different methods are independent).

Comment: Thanks @Cameron. Can you suppose or say what is the porpuse of `long` argument for `ClaseBase` (`ClaseBase<long>`)?

Comment: @JohnOrtizOrdoñez It fixes all uses of `T` *in the definition of `ClassBase`* to `long`.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to make sense of it when you give the classes some content:

```
internal class ClaseBase<T>
{
    public T BaseValue { get; set; }
}
internal class SubclaseGenerica<T> : ClaseBase<long>
{
    public T DerivedValue { get; set; }
}
```

Now look at the properties of `SubclaseGenerica<decimal> sg1 = new SubclaseGenerica<decimal>();`

`BaseValue` is of type `long` and `DerivedValue` is of type `Decimal`.

You've fixed the generic type *used in the base class's definition* to `long`.  You've then created *an entirely different generic argument* that is used to do *entirely different* things in the derived type.

While the code that you have isn't necessarily *wrong*, it's certainly suspicious.  Generally when looking at a closed constructed type one would expect to see something like:

```
internal class SubclaseGenerica : ClaseBase<long>
{
    public long DerivedValue { get; set; }
}
```

Where the derived type *is not itself generic* and is fixing the generic type of the base class.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is certainly an *odd* declaration:

```
internal class SubclaseGenerica<T> : ClaseBase <long> { }
```

In this case, it's a generic type - so it's declaring a *new* type parameter `T`. However, it's supplying a type argument of `long` for `ClaseBase`. So you could write:

```
ClaseBase<long> foo = new SubclaseGenerica<string>();
```

and that would be fine. Any code within `ClaseBase` would see (at execution time) that `T` was `long`, and any code within `SubclaseGenerica` would see (at execution time) that `T` was `string`, because they're two different type parameters.